# Any idea- how can i extend my C drive partition while there is another partition having a gpt flag?

Tags: windows, partitioning

I am in a bad situation here. I need to extend my c drive. I am using AOMEI partitioning tool. But the thing is i can not extend the partition with the C drive in it as there is a 450 mb partition having GPT,WRE flags between this and another one - which i could have easily shrunk. WRE flag stands for WinRE (Windows Recovery Environment). Formatting this drive should be critical, may be(!). So can anyone please tell me how can i possibly extend the c drive partition?[Here is an image of the tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kbxz9.png)

Comment: The GPT flag doesn't matter, all of your partitions have GPT flags, because your drive has a Guid Partition Table.  I am confused about what you are going to extend that c drive with.  There doesn't seem to be any free space after that partition.  In any case, I strongly suggest you make a backup before you start messing around with it.  If it was me, I would just make and verify my backups, and format/reinstall the entire machine.

Comment: "Format/reinstall" works for most people, however many of the "configurations" to each and every windows app and the gazillions of hours spent doing those get wasted so the suggestion to "Format reinstall" only is good for light users. Any power user or more advanced user might consider changing partition sizes as I've answered.  For the user level mentioned, it is not that difficult. Takes a bit longer is equally safe or safer than "format/reinstall" and overall saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a power user/advanced user of Windows then read on... ... You could consider using GParted instead of AOMEI. GParted will easily let you shrink D: (and or E:), move the shrunk partition towards higher cylinders to make space after your 450MB partition and expand your C:, all in one sequence. GParted is free and is included in many Linux distros and can be used right from within the Linux installer without actually installing Linux, or Live editions and other dedicated images available (in other words you have many options on how to run it depending on your system).

Important to get the latest version of GParted you can get your hands on but sometimes the package you get may not be compatible with your hardware (especially hardware in the 2010-2014 timeframe, where many BIOS's were undergoing transition between Legacy and UEFI booting and some can handle/boot from USB 3.0 and some don't and many other quirks like that - my hands bleed from all the Ctrl-Alt-Del's that failed on me!! LOL! ). So this means you may have to try more than one packaging of GParted.

Latest GParted will handle partitions with GPT flag.

PS: Using Clonezilla or something equivalent, to get a full copy of your drive prior to all the changes, is definitely advised. I run a full drive clone into an image and verify it immediately after the cloning operation. Or if you have the money or can spare a disk temporarily, just run a disk to disk copy on another drive of the same or higher size. After all the operations have succeeded, you will no longer need to the backup drive.

PPS: Definitely read [Legacy BIOS Issues with GPT](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/bios.html) and other articles by Rod before embarking on this journey.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on which edition you used. If you use the pro edition, just use Allocate Free Space from a partition to another, here you may allocate the free space in D & E drives to C drive directly. But if you use the free edition, you need to resize D & E to release some free space and merge those unallocated space to C drive. You’d better to back p all your important data before taking actions.

Maybe I should add some guide links to have a better understanding. Check those links:

How to Allocate Free Space - [here](http://www.disk-partition.com/help/allocate-free-space.html)

How to Merge Partitions? - [here](http://www.disk-partition.com/help/merge-partition.html)